# Style not getting overwritten in react-native using styled-components

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to override a button's properties in the calling component using styled-components but it's not working. Nothing gets overridden and the component looks as though it's not taking on the overridden properties.

I've got a button defined like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type ButtonProps = {
  text: string;
};

export const RegularButton = ({text}: (ButtonProps)) => {

  var [ isPress, setIsPress ] = React.useState(false);

  var touchProps = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: '#111111',
    style: isPress ? (styles.btnPress) : (styles.btnNormal),
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPress(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPress(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('HELLO'),
  };

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight  {...touchProps}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnNormal: {
    backgroundColor: '#333333',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  btnPress: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: '#a7a7a7',
    margin: 'auto'
  }
});
```

And an App module that uses it and overrides the style using styled-components:

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from "styled-components";
import { RegularButton } from './components/core/RegularButton'

const MainView = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: 'center';
  justify-content: 'center';
`;

const LevelButton = styled(RegularButton)`
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
`;


export default function App() {
  return (
    <MainView>
      <LevelButton text={"hello"}/>
      <LevelButton text={"hello"}/>

    </MainView>
  );
```

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot get the button to take the width / height, margin, etc. properties that I'm trying to override.

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1816

Answer (score 1):

Your `RegularButton` doesn't accept `style` properties. What you need to do is:

Add `style` to the `ButtonProps`.

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  text: string;
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
};
```

pass the `style` to the component.

```js
export const RegularButton = ({text, style}: (ButtonProps)) => {
```

```js
return (
    <TouchableHighlight {...touchProps} style={style}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

btw, for `react-native` components you should import from `styled-components/native` instead of `styled-components`

Comment: It looks like this is still not working. touchProps already has a style defined, but even trying to add it there didn't work:

        style: [buttonStyle, isPress ? (styles.btnPress) : (styles.btnNormal)],

Using your method above. If I remove this style completely and add it in the return statement, the CSS properties I'm trying to override still don't get overridden.

Comment: that's weird, I tried recreating your button and the `style` seems to work. (btw, I edit the style to be at the end of `TouchableHighlight`). and if you want to use a style to override the previous style you need to put it after the previous style. like this: `[isPress? (styles.btnPress): (styles.btnNormal), newStyle]`.